# Terms For Unknown Dates

Tags: meaning

In a database of artworks when the date that the artwork was made it not exactly known the term circa (ca.), active, late, or early are placed in front of a date.  Would you call these terms 'date qualifiers'?

Comment: Perhaps "date precision specifiers".

Answer (score 1):

Possibly *date qualifiers* is an appropriate name, though it seems a bit "off" in that the term does not immediately bring to mind what it is.

Some alternatives might be:

- date specificity
- date modifier
- date adverb
- date uncertainty
- uncertain date phrase